# Как объединить deliveryCalculator.js и geolocation.js

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-jsapi, yandex-geocoding-api

Доброе время. Пытаюсь не первый день объединить 2 скрипта в 1 выходит ошибка.Какая именно я не знаю тк начал только недавно учиться разработке с картами. Очень нужно для проекта тестового на карте при загрузки Расчёт стоимости доставки подгружалось текущее местоположение телефона по GSM сети.
Помогите плизззз... Ну или ткните на нужный материал для изучения поставленной задачи.
Заранее спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

В примере deliveryCalculator.js есть закоментированные строки, в которых прописан конечный адрес. Нужно добавить определение местоположения пользователя, изменив провайдера геолокации на браузерный, поскольку IP даст слишком уж приблизительное местоположение, и указать обе точки маршрута.

Итоговый фрагмент кода будет выглядеть так:

```
// Определение местоположения пользователя.
var location = ymaps.geolocation.get({provider: 'browser'});
// Метод geolocation.get() возвращает Promise, который
// будет разрешен коллекцией GeoObjectCollection.
// Ссылка на эту коллекцию будет доступна в поле res.geoObjects.
location.then(function (res) {
    // Получение адреса местоположения пользователя.
    var userTextLocation = res.geoObjects.get(0).properties.get('text');
    routePanelControl.routePanel.state.set({
        // В качестве начальной точки маршрута будет установлено
        // местоположение пользователя.
        fromEnabled: false,
        from: userTextLocation,
        // Адрес конечной точки.
        toEnabled: false,
        to: 'Москва, Льва Толстого 16'
    });
});
```

Естественно, конечный адрес вам нужно указать свой.
А итоговая страница на фиддле - https://jsfiddle.net/Coroner1st/za7tc4v8/